# Twitter Bootstrap not displaying in Template

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am following https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0 to include twitter bootstrap into my website. However, When I was testing it out, I'm not getting the expected results. I went on the bootstrap website to test out some of the things I can include on my page but they aren't being display. Please help me with this issue! Thank you!

Here is my HTML file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <div class="modal hide fade">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I've added these portions to my settings.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    ...,
    'registration',
    'twitter_bootstrap',
    'pipeline',
    'homepage',
    )

    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'

    PIPELINE_COMPILERS = (                          # used for compiling LESS files 
        'pipeline.compilers.less.LessCompiler',
    )

    PIPELINE_CSS = {
        'bootstrap': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'less/bootstrap.less',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'css/b.css',
            'extra_context': {
                'media': 'screen,projection',
            },
        },
    }

    PIPELINE_JS = {
        'bootstrap': {
            'source_filenames': (
              'js/transition.js',
              'js/modal.js',
              'js/dropdown.js',
              'js/scrollspy.js',
              'js/tab.js',
              'js/tooltip.js',
              'js/popover.js',
              'js/alert.js',
              'js/button.js',
              'js/collapse.js',
              'js/carousel.js',
              'js/affix.js',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'js/b.js',
        },
        'application': {
            'source_filenames': (
              'js/holder.js',
              'js/application.js',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'js/a.js',
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you got the settings right, but you also need to *load* the compressed files in the html file.

```
{% load compressed %}

<head>
{% compressed_js 'bootstrap' %}
{% compressed_css 'bootstrap' %}
</head>
```

Read more on usage on the documentation (Readme) of [django-bootstrap here](https://github.com/estebistec/django-twitter-bootstrap/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: thank you for the input! I will do just that! Much appreciated!

Comment: Here is what I have now: http://pastebin.com/N7QK9SLf
I just threw in the suggestions you gave me and tossed in some of the things I saw on the site you suggested. However, I am getting a compiler error =/

Comment: Use `{# {% compressed_css 'bootstrap'%} #}` for comments. Also, some issue with the less compiler. That issue is addressed [here](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/issues/99)

Comment: Would you know what the issues might be? commenting out the compressed_css removed the error but twitter bootstrap still isnt displayed =/. I guess errors occur when compressing nonexistent css

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this information Sorry. I feel that the link you sent me isn't referring to Pipeline Less compiler. However, it is a LESS compiler but I'm just not following the discussion in the link you sent me

Comment: check this setting: http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/compilers.html#pipeline-less-binary Have you changed the default location ? S

Comment: I have not actually! I'm not sure how to due this. All the documentation says is "Command line to execute for lessc program. You will most likely change this to the location of lessc on your system.

Defaults to '/usr/bin/env lessc'."

Comment: have you installed less compiler (http://lesscss.org/) ? (have not used less myself, but thats what this looks like)

Comment: I think youre right. I looked through that directory and all i could find was less but not lessc. I'll go do that right now to see if it does the trick!

Comment: So i think I got it working! It's not pretty but it works!! thank you so much for all your help! I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: glad it helped. may be the more you use, you can figure out the pretty way of doing it

Comment: Hey I was wondering if you could help me with one more thing! I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690615/testing-twitter-bootstrap-on-django-badges

I am not use if I am fully implementing TWBS

Comment: looks like someone already  helped you. Sorry, was sleeping :)

Comment: Yes they did haha! but I am using a different method now =/ not django-twitterboostrap app method. You can find out more on my progress but I will not be answering much until I am off work.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696380/bootstrap-files-404-django