# Testing Twitter bootstrap on Django badges

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have twitter bootstrap incorporated on my Django test site but it is not working properly.

I tested out an example of code on the bootstrap website: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#labels-badges

All I had on the site is the success badge (green oval with a 2 in the middle)

```
    <span class="badge badge-success">2</span>
```

However, only the oval and the "2" would be displayed but the green color round the "2" is not  displayed. All I see is a grey oval with a "2" inside. Pretty much the same as the DEFAULT badge on the bootstrap website except there is a "2" instead of a "1".

I was wondering if anyone with Django and twitter bootstrap experience would help me with this issue.

Here is my views.py:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.template import RequestContext, loader
    from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

    def index(request):
        return render(request,'homepage/index.html')
```

Here is my html file:

```
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% load compressed %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
    {% compressed_js 'bootstrap' %}
    {% compressed_css 'bootstrap' %}
    </head>

    <html>
    <body>

    <span class="badge badge-success">2</span>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you for all the help! much appreciated!

Comment: is "2" really displayed in grey or in black ?

Comment: @FoxMaSk
So the badge is all grey but the "2" is white.

Comment: did you try with another badge-xxx CSS class to see if its linked to badge-success or linked to all the badge-xxx CSS class ?

Comment: Ill try that right now!

Comment: @FoxMaSk I just tried every badge and they all have the same output. A grey badge with white text in the middle =/

Comment: it looks like your CSS does not own those classes - on my side i manage the [bootstrap CSS & JS like this](https://github.com/foxmask/django-th/blob/master/django_th/templates/base.html#L12) thus i'm sure what i provide and can check it too. hope this help

Comment: @FoxMaSk Sorry I'm new to twitter bootstrap and mark up languages in general. But I'm assuming that you directly linked your jQuery, CSS, and twitter bootstrap in your template. In other words, linked the mark up libraries from other directories to your template? Correct if I'm wrong please. I'm still learning!

Comment: you're not wrong ;) i put my file css/js from bootstrap in a dir named bootstrap/css and bootstrap/js then call them from the template like you saw in my link. I'm pretty sure that you compressed_css did not work perfectly as your badge-xxx class is not available at all. And I cant answer further more as the SO system will put my answer into the chat .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37037/discussion-between-liondancer-and-foxmask)

Comment: Did you setup `django-pipeline` correctly?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I think I did. Would you like to see my settings.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your compressed_js and compressed_css does not do the trick. 
To check if everything is ok, use for exemple `FireBug`, then press F12 and point your mouse on the badge to see if the CSS rule is display on the left panel. Repeat this step for badge-success to try to find it.

After all of this i'll suggest a more classical way without compressed_xxx :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" %}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

where `bootstrap` is the folder I put in the `static` one I setup in the `settings.py` file

Hope this will be usefull.

Comment: This was incredibly useful THANK YOU!