# Bootstrap files 404 Django

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On FireBug I get these errors

```
    GET http://localhost:8000/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 (NOT FOUND) localhost/:7
    GET http://localhost:8000/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (NOT FOUND) localhost/:8
    GET http://localhost:8000/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

My STATIC_ROOT is :

```
    STATIC_ROOT = '/home/bradford/Development/Django/public_pictures/static'
```

I placed my bootstrap files in a 'static' directory. This 'static' directory is located in my project named 'public_pictures'. I'm not sure why these files can't be located

Here is my HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}" ></script>

    </head>

    <html>
    <body>

    <span class="badge badge-success" >HI!</span>
    <span class="badge">1</span>
    <span class="badge badge-warning">4</span>
    <span class="badge badge-important">6</span>
    <span class="badge badge-info">8</span>
    <span class="badge badge-inverse">10</span>

    </body>
    </html>
```

As a result, only regular text is displayed for these bootstrap badges.

Any input is appreciated thank you!!

***********EDIT**************************

So as of right now my STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py is

```
    STATICFILES_DIR = ('/home/bradford/Development/Django/public_pictures/static',)

    STATIC_ROOT = '', # blank

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    DEBUG = True
```

urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'homepage/',include('homepage.urls', namespace = "homepage")),
        )
```

index.html (template)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load staticfiles %}


    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}" ></script>

    </head>

    <html>
    <body>

    <span class="badge badge-success" >HI!</span>
    <span class="badge">1</span>
    <span class="badge badge-warning">4</span>
    <span class="badge badge-important">6</span>
    <span class="badge badge-info">8</span>
    <span class="badge badge-inverse">10</span>

    </body>
    </html>
```

All these changes lead me a bit closer to my goal. However the badges of the bootstrap is displayed but there is no color being displayed. Everything is grey with white text =[ I'm not sure if the other features work as well. I shall try them. Thank you again for all the help! much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the django development server or is this being served through Apache?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ i assume this is on development server. are you sure your urls are set up properly?

Comment: @fsw pretty sure i did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Development Server:**

Leave `STATIC_ROOT` empty.

Make a change to **STATICFILES_DIRS**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

'/home/bradford/Development/Django/public_pictures/static',

)
```

Run `./manage.py collectstatic`

Should work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have forgot to include your static url in urls.py. If you are using development server you can use the following code in urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

More reference on deploying static files for [development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) or for [production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/).